# Iterating stepwise through permutations of arbitrary sets in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, permutation

I'm trying to find an elegant way to iterate stepwise through all possible permutations of an arbitrary number of sets, or "buckets". I need to do it stepwise because I'm dealing with a great number of possible permutations, and have been running out of memory space trying to store all permutations in memory and then weed out the ones that are invalid. Instead, I am trying to step through each permutations one at a time, and only store it in a final list in memory if it's valid, so that I can save some memory space.

I've been trying to write out a manual solution for this, and it's proven to be a bit difficult - I don't want to know exactly how many lists/sets I'm dealing with, so I can't take the brute force approach of creating a series of nested for loops. Creating a custom iterator for this has proven to be its own set of challenges.

I was hoping that there would be some built-in methods or tools I can leverage for this without reinventing the wheel.

Here is an example: Let's say I have a couple sets of letters:

```
[a, b, c], [n, c, a]
```

And my goal is to find all possible permutations of letters from these two "buckets", but only those that do not have duplicates in their sets (in a real world example there could be more complex requirements, just using this simple one for the sake of the example). So all possible permutations are:

```
[a, n], [a, c], [a, a], 
[b, n], [b, c], [b, a],
[c, n], [c, c], [c, a].
```

Now that I have all possible permutations, I want to weed out the ones that don't satisfy the requirements: `[a, a] and [c, c]`.

Rather than weeding those out after the fact (and taking up space in temporary memory where it could otherwise be filled by a valid combination), I want to check at each created permutation if it's valid before storing it in memory.

Is there anything built into Kotlin that'd make this easier?

EDIT: I was able to figure out how I could do this by creating my own "iterator" class that steps through each permutation, and "bubbles up" if the final set has been looped through completely, in order to make sure I hit each permutation. I can post the solution here if anyone in interested by the (probably slightly inefficient) solution, but I would still like to know if there was an easier way to do this using some built in Kotlin tools.

Comment: Could you provide an example for more sets?  I am not sure if [a], [b], [c] should be [a, b, c] or [a, b], [a,c], [b, c].

Comment: So each "bucket" would correspond to an index in the final set. If I wanted my resulting set to have 5 elements for example, I would need to be choosing one element from 5 different "buckets". Does that help clarify? In your example, if I started out with 3 separate sets, that means the result would contain a sets with 3 elements each. So if I started out with sets [a], [b], [c], the only possible permutation would be [a, b, c]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, what you're asking for is the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of sets.  (‘[Permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)’ usually refers to different orderings of all the elements of a single set, or of subsets thereof.)

Doing this directly is easy, using [`map()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) and [`flatMap()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html):

```
operator fun <T, U> Iterable<T>.times(other: Iterable<U>)
    = flatMap{ a -> other.map{ b -> a to b }}
```

(`operator fun… times` is a bit of magic that lets you [overload](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) the `*` operator.  `T` and `U` are [type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/generics.html#generic-type-parameters), so this will work for sets of any type.  And [`to`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html) is an easy way to construct a `Pair`.)

However, as you say, that creates a list of results, and if you want to do any filtering or other post-processing, that would create another.

The usual way to avoid that is to use [sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html).  (Equivalent to Java [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).)  These are lazy structures, in which elements are only evaluated when needed.

Normally it's as easy as adding [`.asSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-sequence.html) to the list, but because we have two of them here, it's rather tricker…  Here's one way:

```
operator fun <T, U> Iterable<T>.times(other: Iterable<U>): Sequence<List<Pair<T, U>> {
    val otherSeq = other.asSequence()
    return asSequence().flatMap{ a -> otherSeq.map{ b -> a to b }}
}
```

That returns a [`Sequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence/), so you can do any filtering or other post-processing you want, and then call a terminal operation such as [`toList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/to-list.html) afterward to actually perform the computation:

```
val result = (setOf('a', 'b', 'c') * setOf('n', 'c', 'a'))
            .filter{ it != 'a' to 'a' && it != 'c' to 'c' }
            .toList()
println(result)
// prints: [(a, n), (a, c), (b, n), (b, c), (b, a), (c, n), (c, a)]
```

(I'm not too experienced with sequences, so I'm not guaranteeing that's the *most* efficient way…)

Comment: That's an awesome looking solution! I think the sequences bit was exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. One thing that I'm trying to wrap my head around now is how I could extend your solution to account for an arbitrary number of sets to start, and namely how that would change the `times` operator. So if there were 3 sets to begin with for example, I think with the current implementation it would end up with something like ((a, b), c). That could probably be fixed by flattening out those pairs into just a list of values?

Comment: Yes, you could extend it to multiple sets, though that would be a little fiddly.  (I'd probably want to change the `times()` function to take two Sequences, instead of creating them; then you could use `setA.asSequence() * setB.asSequence() * …`.)  But, as you say, that would create Pairs of Pairs…  You could use Lists instead, probably with judicious use of `flatten()`, but then you'd be creating lots of temporary objects, which is what we wanted to avoid…

Comment: good point - honestly even after finally implementing something like this, I realized the sheer number of data I'm dealing with for my little side project, there ends up being hundreds of millions of "valid" permutations, so this intermediary filtering didn't help as much as I thought it would... I think I'll have to segment my inputs and resulting sets into separate computations. 
But I'm glad I learned something about sequences anyway, your solution is certainly much more elegant than mine haha